# Flac error when decoding

Tags: audio-conversion, flac

I have a song that cannot be converted or decoded or played with any player.

When I use a flac frontend to attempt decoding i get the error:

> 1. flac: ERROR, --until value is before --skip point
> 2. Some Song.flac: ERROR while decoding metadata
>                                      state = FLAC__STREAM_DECODER_END_OF_STREAM

I attempted to google the error but no luck for me.

The first image in a hex editor is the broken one, looks like the MP3 tag is missing, maybe more.

The second is a good flac file.

[image]

[image]

Is this repairable and how?

I am using Windows 7

Comment: Have you tried a file converter, such as File Converter, https://file-converter.org ? If that doesn't work, your file may be badly damaged.

Comment: i can open it with a hex editor, that's it.

Comment: What does the file look like in hex? the EOS error implies it's truncated... look for a bunch of NUL bytes.

Comment: Actually the good file has a bunch of null bytes, i see this a lot in hex editing. Check my edit.

Comment: Though it has a FLAC header, the first (bad) file seems to have a very different body. It's possible 7-Zip might open it as an archive... or not. Try to get another copy of the file.